# retrieving XML parameter value via PHP

Tags: php, xml

I'm just trying to get the URL value from the below XML code.  I'm having problems getting past the category parameter:

```
<ImageSets>
    <ImageSet Category="primary">
        <SwatchImage>
            <URL>www.url.jpg</URL>
        </SwatchImage>
    </ImageSet>
</ImageSets>
```

I searched, but haven't found a similar question; they all end at the parameter tag; they don't go down another node level.  I tried this code, but am getting error messages that aren't very intuitive:

```
ImageSets->ImageSet->attributes()->Category['primary']->SwatchImage->URL
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show us also the code you have tried so we can correct it.

Comment: what xml parser are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `xpath` in `simplexml` to do the job:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assuming XML in $x

$urls = $xml-xpath("//imageset[@Category = 'primary']/SwatchImage/URL");
```

This `xpath` statement will select all `<URL>`s under all `<imageset>`s whose attribute `Category = primary` and store those in the array `$urls`.

```
foreach ($urls as $url) echo "$url<br />"; // output all
```

If you need the first `<URL>` only (PHP >= 5.4):

```
$url = (string)$xml-xpath("//imageset[@Category = 'primary']/SwatchImage/URL")[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I got your question right, but I'd do something like:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("file.xml");
echo $xml->ImageSet[0]->SwatchImage->URL;
```

Does it fix it?
In case give me more data so that I can edit the code. Works for me though.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to get `URL` of `ImageSet` which has `Category="primary"`, Then you can get it like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string("<?xml version='1.0' ?>
    <ImageSets>
        <ImageSet Category='primary'>
            <SwatchImage>
                <URL>www.url.jpg</URL>
            </SwatchImage>
        </ImageSet>
    </ImageSets>
    ");

$primary_url = '';
foreach ($xml->ImageSet as $set) {
    if ($set->attributes()->Category == 'primary') {
        $primary_url = $set->SwatchImage->URL;
        break;
    }
}
echo $primary_url;
```